# QML: How to destroy or stop workerscript in QML

Tags: qt, qml, qt-quick

I am trying to use `WorkerScript` for loading list model elements in QML.
But how can we stop `WorkerScript` once we are done with the update;
is there any way of destroying or stopping the `WorkerScript` ?

Answer (score 0):

I think the worker script will stop as soon as it finishes executing.

Comment: Since `XMLHttpRequest.onTimeout` apparently doesn't work in WorkerScripts, couldn't it in principle run forever?

Comment: @tanghus I haven't used WorkerScript in a long time. I will get back with more details after reading some information about it.